# Express sessionID changed on every Nuxt Auth request

Tags: express, nuxt.js, express-session, nuxt-auth

I'm new to Nuxt Auth and express session, when I perform `this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: '' })`, I will set `req.session.loggedIn = true` in the server, and I can see my req.session.id = 'xxx' for example.

After that, the nuxt auth will make another call to `/api/auth/user`, but I can see the sessionID has been changed, and req.session.loggedIn was `undefined`.

How can I maintain the same session for every request?

Below is my config

```
 auth: {
        strategies: {
          local: {
            token: {
              required: false,
              type: false
            },
            endpoints: {
              login: { url: '/api/auth/login', method: 'POST' },
              logout: { url: '/api/auth/logout', method: 'POST' },
              user: { url: '/api/auth/user', method: 'get' }
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

I'm using v5

```
"@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1616003482.75c20e6",
```